# Cannot override matplotlib format_coord

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm creating a contour plot with a list of V values as the x-axis and a list of T values as the y-axis (the V and T values are float numbers with 2 digits after the decimal point but all sorted of course). I created a data matrix and populated it with the data correlating with the V-T coordinates.

If it helps anything, this is what the contour plot would look like:

[image]

I'm trying to override the format_coord method to also display the data along with the x-y (V-T) coordinates when the cursor moves

I can't post all my code here, but here are the relevant parts:

```
fig= Figure()
a = fig.add_subplot(111)

contour_plot = a.contourf(self.pre_formating[0],self.pre_formating[1],datapoint) #Plot the contour on the axes

def fmt(x, y):
    '''Overrides the original matplotlib method to also display z value when moving the cursor
    '''
    V_lst = self.pre_formating[0] #List of V points
    T_lst = self.pre_formating[1] #List of T points
    Zflat = datapoint.flatten()   #Flatten out the data matrix
    print 'first print line'
    # get closest point with known v,t values
    dist = distance.cdist([x,y],np.stack([V_lst, T_lst],axis=-1))
    print 'second print line'
    closest_idx = np.argmin(dist) 
    z = Zflat[closest_idx]
    return 'x={x:.5f}  y={y:.5f}  z={z:.5f}'.format(x=x, y=y, z=z)
a.format_coord = fmt
```

The above code does not work (when I move the cursor nothing shows up, even the x,y value. The 'first print line' gets printed but the 'second print line' doesn't, so I think the problem is with the 'dist' line).

But when I change the 'dist' line to

```
dist = np.linalg.norm(np.vstack([V_lst - x, T_lst - y]), axis=0)
```

Everything works (x,y,data shows up) for a 37x37 matrix but not for a 37x46 matrix (37T, 46V) and I don't know why. 
What should I do to make my code work?
Thank you for helping!

Comment: The problem seems to be unrelated to matplotlib or the format_coord function. If you have a problem with the lines `dist = ...`, provide a [mcve] of the issue. Don't forget to clearly state the expected outcome of that operation and remove all irrelevant parts, like matplotlib, from the problem. But make sure it is runnable.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. The dist = ... is supposed to return a list of distances from that (x,y) coordinate to the list of points we have data of. I found out the problem, it is because cdist requires everything in the form of a 2d array, so changing it to dist = distance.cdist([[x,y]],np.stack([V_lst, T_lst],axis=-1)) solves everything! Thank you for your advice!

Comment: also I was wrong in my way of generating a list of coordinates. I'll post the full solution to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys so I found out how to solve this in case anyone needs it. There were 2 problems:
1/ I was wrong in my way of generating a list of V,T coordinates
2/ distance.cdist requires everything in the form of a 2d array.
So this is the final solution:

```
def fmt(x, y):
    '''Overrides the original matplotlib method to also display z value when moving the cursor
    '''
    V_lst = self.pre_formating[0] #List of V points
    T_lst = self.pre_formating[1] #List of T points
    coordinates = [[v,t] for t in T_lst for v in V_lst] # List of coordinates (V,T)
    Zflat = datapoint.flatten()   #Flatten out the data matrix
    # get closest point with known v,t values
    dist = distance.cdist([[x,y]],coordinates)
    closest_idx = np.argmin(dist)
    z = Zflat[closest_idx]
    return 'x={x:.5f}  y={y:.5f}  z={z:.5f}'.format(x=x, y=y, z=z)
```